# mysqldump takes forever to dump tables from a remote server

Tags: backup, mysqldump, schema-copy

I'm trying to pull the database schema from a remote server, but `mysqldump` is too slow to output (125+) tables' structures.

- If I enter the said server and run `mysqldump --compact --compress --no-data --add-drop-database --databases --user=myuser --password=123 mydb > dump.sql` it's almost instant.
- If I run the same thing over ssh it takes 2.5 secs (`ssh myserver mysqldump [...] > dump.sql`)
- However, if I use the `--host` so I can use the database credentials only, instead of the SSH credentials, it takes 2min40s to run!

What makes mysqldump so slow when running over its own protocol? It dumps each table (all at once) every few seconds, then waits, dumps the next one...
Is there anything I could do to make things faster?

EDIT: I [wrote about that db adventure](https://medium.com/@igorsantos07/a-not-so-small-rant-on-mysql-based-techniques-to-copy-database-structures-4333f8ff8384#.8qiega4cq), to show the final solutions.

Comment: Have you tried scripting getting the ssh dump over to your own machine - i.e. make it a two-step process? You could pipe dump sql to rcp or similar?

Comment: @Vérace yeah, the issue is not with the steps but with the need to use ssh to make it in a decent speed. MySQL credentials should be enough, why's its protocol so slow in this case?

Comment: Do you have this problem with other remote servers?

Comment: I don't have any other to test... My other projects' dbs are either not accessible through the internet or pgsql-based :(

Comment: Can you share the full SSH command you are using and the full command you are using with --host? What is the size on disk of `dump.sql`? How long does it take to transfer `dump.sql` with scp from the remote machine to your local machine? Is compression turned on for ssh? If not you could change the end of your command slightly to be `mysqldump ... | gzip -c > dump.sql.gz`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and regarding the "why" this happens, my theory is that it's due to network overhead of opening/closing connections.
My theory is that mysqldump needs to open and closes a lot of connections and that's what's slowing it down.

I ran it on the machine itself and it took 10 seconds.
From another machine, through a VPN, it took like 10 minutes.
From another machine on the same network (connected to the same switch), it took 20 seconds.

It's just a theory but it fits those observations.

Of course to work around that issue, the ssh trick works.